# JS/jQuery check if element is typable

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to check if an element is able to be typed into, specifically `document.activeElement` so that I can use shift+key as keyboard shortcuts without obstructing user's abilities to type in whatever input may be focused upon.

How would I go about deciding whether an element is able to typed into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [isContentEditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/isContentEditable) property

```
$('my-element-selector').is('[contenteditable="true"]')
```

or

```
$('my-element-selector').get(0).isContentEditable
```

Or try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/rtdhsu4w/)

```
<div id='el1'></div>
<input id='inp1' type='text'>

function isEditable($element)
{
  return $element.is( "input:text:not(:disabled):not([readonly]), textarea:text:not(:disabled):not([readonly])" ) ;
}

console.log( isEditable( $('#el1') ) );
console.log( isEditable( $('#inp1') ) );
```

Updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/rtdhsu4w/3/) again to add support for more input ty

```
function isEditable($element)
{
  return $element.is( "input[type!='radio'][type!='checkbox'][type!='date']:not(:disabled):not([readonly]), textarea:text:not(:disabled):not([readonly])" ) ;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this only work for divs? And not inputs/textareas.

Comment: @SebastianKing try the fiddle I have shared

Comment: It still doesn't support email inputs or password inputs, I take it there isn't some sort of jQuery function that has all of this stuff factored in already?

Comment: textarea:text does not seem to work for me, but removing the :text pseudo did. Also any reason to use pseudo for disabled and not readonly? This appears to work fine in Chrome: `textarea:not([disabled]):not([readonly])`

Answer (score 1):

If you check document.activeElement.tagName you can decide whether the element is an input or it is a text area.

if it is input, check for $(document.activeElement).attr("type") which will give you the type of input. if it is not button, radio, checkbox etc, then it is an editable input field.

Also if $(document.activeElement).attr("contenteditable") is true then it will be an editable field.